# Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.rafaquarta.whatsapp.model.Usuario

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The program works fluently on start, but after I mistakenly remove the database, there began the error dumbing. Really I don't understand why ?. The error code is

```
 Process: com.rafaquarta.whatsapp, PID: 6886
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.rafaquarta.whatsapp.model.Usuario
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:435)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:231)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:79)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:203)
        at com.rafaquart
```

And the code where I face the issue is

```
 valueEventListenerContatos = usuariosRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                limparListaContatos();

                for(DataSnapshot dados: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){


                    Usuario usuario = dados.getValue(Usuario.class);

                    String emailUsuarioAtual = usuarioAtual.getEmail();
                    if(!emailUsuarioAtual.equals(usuario.getEmail())){
                        listaContatos.add(usuario);
                    }

                }

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

In this code, I face error in

```
Usuario usuario = dados.getValue(Usuario.class);
```

The database:

[image]

If anyone know any solution please help. I'm in a situation here. Why the error I don't understand. I checked 
[com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type models.firebase.FirebaseTripDataHolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59122830/com-google-firebase-database-databaseexception-cant-convert-object-of-type-jav?noredirect=1&lq=1)

and this
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51156959/cant-convert-object-of-type-java-lang-string?noredirect=1&lq=1)

If anyone knows any solution please help me.

Comment: What is usuariosRef? and can you please post your database screenshot?

Comment: Actually are trying to convert `string` into `Usuario` object. can you show you  firebase structure

Comment: Please add this line in your for loop: `Map<String, Object> data = dataSnapshot.getChildren();` Run and debug on this line & check.

Comment: Sure here is my link https://i.ibb.co/4gg0y5k/Capture.jpg

Comment: Sure if your response convert into JSON then ping me @BugsBUNNY

Comment: i think dados.getValue is a String class so u can not write dados.getValue(Usuario.class); with your model class. Try this way String temp =dados.getValue(String.class); and after that Usuario usuario = new Usuario(); and usuario.your_string=temp; get it or i should write new asnwer?

Comment: @Ali I get error incompatible types.

Comment: @BugsBUNNY Sry i forgot to tell you please add this two line: `Map<String, Object> data = dc.getDocument().getData();`
`JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);`

Comment: @pratik vekariya I got small idea from that but usuario.your_string=temp; how to save the value from it to a string.

Comment: @BugsBUNNY create one string value in your Usuario class like String abc=""; so usuario.abc=temp; now your value saved in usuario

Comment: @Ali I think the variable dc is data class when I put that getdeocument makes issues

Comment: thank you all and everyone who answered my question and helped me. I found the solution myself as I told you guys... The issue just started after I lost the database... I just remade a database from my old project and tried my luck .... merlin's beard!!!.... it working... I thought the database may be causing the issue. Thanks again to all brothers in arms

Answer (score 1):

**Usuario usuario = dados.getValue(Usuario.class);**

In this line you get String data from firebse, but you try to Receive as Userio.class

You need change from Userio.class to String.class, And debug In this line And check which data come from Firebase And I think you get Idea about what is wrong.

Because I think You reference Firebase basedatabase improperly , I mean you Reference with wrong collection child.

Comment: The Usuario.class is a helper class that I made.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase=  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
 usuariosRef= firebaseDatabase.child("usuarios")
```

then you call `addValueEventListener` for `usuariosRef`.
Currently you might `addValueEventListener` for wrong location and that why it is returning String

Comment: I set this code already on top. It is working well.  but still the issue persists

Comment: Can you show your full code including `Model class`.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
                for(DataSnapshot dados: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){


                    Usuario usuario = dados.getValue(Usuario.class);

                    String emailUsuarioAtual = usuarioAtual.getEmail();
                    if(!emailUsuarioAtual.equals(usuario.getEmail())){
                        listaContatos.add(usuario);
                    }

                }
```

into this:

```
 Usuario usuario = dataSnapshot.getValue(Usuario.class);

String emailUsuarioAtual = usuarioAtual.getEmail();
if(!emailUsuarioAtual.equals(usuario.getEmail())){
     listaContatos.add(usuario);
  }
 }
```

Remove the for loop, since when you iterate you are retrieving the data of type `String`, and in your code you are trying to map the retrieved data to your pojo class.

Comment: Bro when I try that it says mail is null

Comment: which mail bro, you have two mails

Comment: check if this is null `usuario.getEmail()` use a `Log` -- this is the data you are retrieving.

Answer (score 1):

for example in your data base

```
 {
 'account':{
       'user':{

                 'id0':{//some data here    
                      },
                 'id1'{},
               }
            }
  }
```

now,May be you reference with **account** and you get String it mean **user**,But you need to **id**.

So if you Change it from Userio.class to String.class, and debug the you get child string so you get idea which child actual for you model.And later you change form String.class to Userio.class with proper child.

In Details;

**usuariosRef** is your firebase ref .

For example

you **usuariosRef**  ref with **account** child. Inside **account** exist **user**  child, Here you can see only one String exist that is **user**.So you get String from firebase. **But you need  id** .You need reference firebase with **user** , so you cen get **id** mean **usuariosRef** .

Comment: can you share a bit more explanation, bro? I understand this but little confused.

Comment: I have added more detail in my answer check it.